# Number of messages consumed from MQTT broker seems to be capped

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

I'm running a Go service that uses the Paho Go MQTT client for subscribing to a topic. The clients that produce the MQTT messages (also Paho, but on Android devices) log when they produce and my service logs when it receives. As you can see from this graph, there seems to be a pretty consistent "cap" right below 36.000 messages per day on the receiving side. The graphs follow each other almost perfectly up to the cap, but then it seems that the go service caps out on slightly below 600 messages per minute, which means around 10 msgs per second.

Where should I look for the solution to this? I cannot find any setting (options) that could explain this cap.

[image: 2-day view]

[image: Each point is 1 minute]

Comment: You say messages increase up to a daily cap; that seems to indicate that things start working again the next day? Generally such issues end up being caused by the message handler blocking so I'd start there (not saying this is the cause here, there is not enough info to make an assessment)

Comment: I don't think there is a setting for this. The only explanation I can think of is that the receiver service can only process around 10 messages per second. I would start by checking how long it takes the service to process one message and calculate the throughput. Assuming that your message handler works in blocking mode, you can try to increase the throughput by processing the messages in separate goroutines.

Comment: Where is the Go client running? Are all the messages the same size? is there a daily bandwidth cap? Does the Go client stay connected to the broker (look at both client and broker logs)

Comment: @Brits The "cap" is not a hard cap and then they stop. It's more like a rate cap. The service seemingly handles all messages up to the mentioned rate and then it flats out. It still handles messages just fine, but apparently not at the same rate as they are produced. And so it seems it loses messages, although there are no indications that it drops them. It seems like it never receives them. Like if the broker said "hey, that's too many messages for you, i'll feed you just 10 per second max"

Comment: @EminLaletovic The service runs in kubernetes and the pod uses very little resources. As far as I can tell, the Paho already handles messages in separate goroutines, but I will look into that. My theory, though, would be that the total number of messages should be the same during the day as when the load goes down, the subscriber should be able to catch up if the rate was the issue. Also, it should have logged errors if it had issues with consuming messages, I would think...

Comment: @hardillb It is running in kubernetes on aws. There is no cap and there are other services consuming many more messages at a higher rate than this one. There is even a different (old) service consuming from the same topic that seems to get all the messages. So it seems there is something special with MY service. I don't have access to broker logs, but I can request that someone looks into that. But yes, the client stays connected according to its own logs.

Comment: I had thought the Paho client triggers a goroutine for each message it consumes as the Subcribe doc says "callback must be safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.", but maybe this is not the case. I'm now triggering a goroutine myself in the handler to see if that helps. The handler does indeed spend 100ms per messages, which could explain the apparent "cap" on the consume rate (but I still don't understand why it doesn't catch up once the load goes below this)

Comment: By default messages are delivered in order (so the library waits for the handler to return before sending another). See ["common problems"](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang#common-problems) in the readme. You are probably hitting a "max in flight messages" limit and the broker is dropping messages (e.g. mosquitto defaults to 20). What QOS level are you using?

Comment: @Brits I'm using QOS 1 and it does indeed seem like the broker is dropping messages. And the readme says "silently dropping" which is the crux here that I had overlooked. I had expected some kind of warning if messages were dropped.
Firing a separate goroutine for each incoming message seems to have solved the problem. We are at one of the daily peaks now and the number of consumed messages equal the number of sent, well above the previous capped rate. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I didn't see it being mentioned anywhere, do you know if you are using a persistent session? If not, the broker might not be queueing messages.
https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/

Comment: Yes, it is persistent. Issue is solved now. Thank you @EminLaletovic

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments [`paho.mqtt.golang`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang#common-problems) defaults to ordered delivery of messages (the [MQTT spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718105) provides some guarantees re message ordering and and calling handlers in a go routine may break this). The upshot of this is that messages will be delivered one-by-one and, if your handler is not keeping up, a queue may form (at QOS1+ the broker needs to retain messages as it may be necessary to resend them).

Some brokers limit the number of messages queued for a client; for example the `max_queued_messages` option in Mosquitto defaults to 1000 (this default was lower in [Mosquitto 1.X](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/v1.6.15/man/mosquitto.conf.5.xml#L654)) and, if the queue exceeds the limit, "messages will be silently dropped".

This is what appears to have been happening here; the application was not keeping up with incoming messages so the broker began dropping messages when the queue exceeded a limit.

In many cases using the `paho.mqtt.golang`option `ClientOptions.SetOrderMatters(false)` will help; with this option set the message handler will be called in a [separate go routine](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/router.go#L187) (so the handler must be threadsafe). Alternatively start a go routine within the handler but note that this approach results in the `ACK` being sent before the handler completes (which may result in message loss if your application terminates unexpectedly).